# Roles in Java Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Does anyone have any recommendations for me on how to manage user roles on the Java version of Google App Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documentation [states here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication)

> App Engine does not support custom security roles () or alternate authentication mechanisms () in the deployment descriptor.
>   Security constraints apply to static files as well as servlets.

So you do not left with much other then coding work with ACLs in to your app all by hand and this is highly application design dependent.